# how to send email before due date based on number of business days in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I want to send an email before due date based on number of business days .
For example :- 
If I want to send email 2 days before due date lets say on 21st of month but 19th and 20th are weekends and 18th is company's own holiday. It should calculate the working days and generate notification on 16th .

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not have any tools in the box that identify business days. Conceptually:

- Create a list with holiday dates.
- for the main list, use a workflow that sets the notification date. The workflow will work out the weekday of the due date and look up the due date in the holiday list and then subtract the required number of days from the due date, taking into account weekends.
- create a workflow that sends the reminder email
- create a view with all items where the notification date is today
- use a tool like the free [HarePoint Workflow scheduler](https://www.harepoint.com/Products/HarePointWorkflowScheduler/Default.aspx) to run the workflow that sends the email on all items in that view

Comment: @DikeshGandhi, I am rolling back your edit. There is a company called HarePoint and they have a product called HarePoint Workflow Scheduler. It is not a typo. And please don't get picky on the capital P mid-word. That's not an edit reason

Comment: I'm really very sorry....